# Unexpected file path and FileNotFoundException in ContentResolver - Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to feed `MediaRecorder` with a filePath to save a video and in order to do that I use `insert` method which returns a `Uri`. I then take this `Uri` and query for the `DATA` column to obtain my file path to then pass it to `mediaRecorder.setOutputFile()`. To my surprise, even though I pass `contentValues` map with `DISPLAY_NAME` set in format `timestamp.mp4`, the file path I end up with is compeletely different and has a `.3gp` suffix.

Below is the code fragment which inserts the media and retrieves the filePath.

```java
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
        Uri mediaStoreUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, timeStamp + ".mp4");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        Uri videoUri = getContentResolver().insert(mediaStoreUri, contentValues);
        String videoPath = getRealUriPath(videoUri);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoPath);
```

and the method `getRealUriPath` looks as follows

```java
   private String getRealUriPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA;
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I start recording with the `mMediaRecorder`, an exception is thrown which looks as follows:

```
07-31 19:08:36.240 1895-1895/com.example.opencv101 E/CameraActivity: MediaRecorder failed to prepare.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/video/1627751307861.3gp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I don't understand two things:

- Why does the filePath end with `1627751307861.3gp` ?
- Why do I get the `FileNotFoundException` since I'm trying to access the file I've just added using the `insert` method?

I double checked that the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions are granted.

Comment: What sense does it have to use the mediastore where you want to use a file system path? You can imagine such a path yourself i think.

Comment: Which Android version on used device?

Comment: Well I use MediaStore because I'd like the videos to be saved in a place that will be visible by other apps too. The Android on my device is 6.0.1.

Comment: I suppose I could do something like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getPath()` but then how would I query those movies using ContentResolver?

Comment: You would not query using the content resolver but use new File(path).listFiles(). Or else... What is it that you wanna query?